# Given two concentric circles with radiuses r < R, can we estimate the number of chords in between the circles?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry

Given two concentric circles with radiuses $r < R$, can we estimate the number of chords in between the circles?

With more details, fix a point $P$ on the inner circle. Trace a tangent to the inner circle through that point, this defines the chord, e.g. $AB$, with both $A$ and $B$ on the outer circle. From B, trace another tangent to the inner circle, this defines chord $BC$, where $C$ is on the outer circle. Same procedure to define the chord $CD$. Now, if $CD$ intersects $AB$ we stop, otherwise we continue until one of the constructed chords intersects $AB$.

Obviously $AB=2\cdot\sqrt{R^{2}-r^{2}}$. Which also means $AB=BC=CD=...$

Is it possible to estimate the number of chords, following the above construction, given $r$ and $R$? It obviously is $\geqslant 3$. A very raw estimation is $2\cdot \pi \cdot r< AB\cdot n_{of chords} < 2\cdot \pi \cdot R$, anything more precise with some clever geometrical hacks?

Also, noting $\alpha =\frac{r}{R}$, then $\pi \cdot \alpha < \sqrt{1-\alpha ^{2}}\cdot n_{of chords} < \pi$. And when $\frac{r}{R}\rightarrow 1\Rightarrow n_{of chords}\rightarrow \infty$. Is it possible to estimate $\frac{n_{of chords}}{R}$ given that $r\rightarrow \infty$ as well?

Remark 1: $n_{of chords} \sim \frac{\pi }{\sqrt{1-\alpha ^{2}}}=\pi \cdot {\left ( \arcsin\alpha  \right )}'$

Remark 2: To make things more evident, just replace $r=\sqrt{p_{n}}$ and $R=\sqrt{p_{n+1}}$, then $r=p_{n}$ and $R=p_{n+1}$, where $p_{n}, p_{n+1}$ - two consecutive primes.

**UPDATE:** Just to avoid unnecessary negative voting, there is this book "Recreational Mathematics" by Paul Yiu (http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/RecreationalMathematics2003.pdf). First 2 chapters are dedicated to lattice points and polygons. I am after something similar, but in conjunction with the problem described.

Comment: I read this post 17 hours after it has been posted. Purely judging from the title, (hoping that my interpretation to it is correct), the answer is simply infinitely many. Let say P(K) is a point as suggested and it has n(P(K)) number of chords. But K can run from 1 to infinity. From this point of view, there are infinitely many chords can be generated already. Not to mention that P is not a point on the inner circle. There are also infinitely many of them.

Comment: Yes, it goes to infinity, but how "quickly"?

Comment: By "quickily", I guess you mean, for a particular K, how fast does the index runs from 1 to n(P(K)).

Comment: Yes, sort of. 

For this particular case when $r=\sqrt{p_{n}}$ and $R=\sqrt{p_{n+1}}$, knowing that $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}<n$ from some n and $\sqrt{p_{n+1} - p_{n}} \geq \sqrt{2}$, $n_{of chords} < \frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\cdot n$.

Comment: Another way, probably, to tackle the problem (and this is a brainstorming): $$n_{of chords}\sim \frac{\pi }{\sqrt{1-\alpha ^{2}}}=\pi \cdot \sqrt{1+\alpha ^{2}+\alpha ^{4}+...}< \pi \cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n}^{\infty }\alpha ^{2\cdot i}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $\angle AOP$ ($O$ is the center of the circles).
Then $\cos \alpha = r/R$ .

Therefore, in each step the point on the outer circle "advances" by the angle
$$
\angle AOB = \angle BOC = \dots = 2 \alpha = 2 \arccos \frac rR \quad .
$$
You get an intersection as soon as the point on the outer circle has advanced
by $2 \pi$ or more, therefore the number of "chords" is the largest integer $n$ such that
$$
   n \lt \frac \pi {\arccos (r/R)}  \quad.
$$

Comment: True. I was thinking of something in form of an asymptotic function $f(r,R)$. Can't find anything with google and I don't believe this problem was never touched.

Comment: @rtybase: $$n \sim \frac \pi {\sqrt{1 - (r/R)^2}}$$ for $r/R \to 1$ follows from the above formula. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, that's one of it, mentioned in "Remark 1". Considering that $\sin \angle AOB = \sqrt{1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}}\sim \angle AOB$ when $\frac{r}{R}\rightarrow 1$ this leads to the close to the intuition result $n_{of chords}\sim \frac{\pi }{\angle AOB}$. However, this doesn't help with estimating $\frac{n_{of chords}}{R}$, when $r\rightarrow \infty $ ... for more details, I am trying to "asses" Andrica's conjecture and see if I get any luck with estimating $n_{of chords}$.

Comment: So far, I have got to $\sqrt{p_{n+1}} - \sqrt{p_{n}} < \frac{\sqrt{p_{n+1}}}{2}\cdot \ln\frac{\sqrt{p_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{p_{n}}} < C\cdot \frac{\sqrt{p_{n+1}}}{n_{of chords}^2}$

Comment: @rtybase: Sorry, I do not understand. You asked for a better estimate for $n$ and I gave you the exact formula. The asymptotic formula above follows from that, so it is not a "intuition result". Do you need a proof? In the special case $r = \sqrt{p_n}$, $R = \sqrt{p_{n+1}}$ you get $n \sim \pi / \sqrt{1-p_{n+1}/p_n}$  - Your other questions about the asymptotic behaviour are unclear to me.

Comment: Ok, let me reformulate my previous message. 
1. I knew of that asymptotic expression (Remark 1).
2. Unfortunately, it doesn't help.
3. Is there a better one?

"Intuition result", had a different context, I shouldn't have mentioned it, probably.

Comment: And probably "Is there a better one?" is a wrong formulation, should have written "Is there a different one?".

Comment: @rtybase: Are you looking for an estimate that utilizes the fact that the radii are square roots of prime numbers? I do not think that there is a fundamentally better or different estimate, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: yes, that's the ultimate goal ;)